# Towards understanding availability of xdg-open

Tags: c, linux, availability, xdgutils

I want to open an image, and in Windows I do:

```
#include <windows.h>
..
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2018/11/chronosgod.png", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I would like to use a Linux approach, where it's so much easier to run something on the fly. Example:

```
char s[100];
snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%s %s", "xdg-open", "https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2018/11/chronosgod.png");
system(s);
```

In my Ubuntu, it works. However, when running that in Wandbox (<kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dCyXUR89QGGTa5A6)</kbd>), or in any other online compiler, I would most likely get an error:

> sh: 1: xdg-open: not found

despite the fact that these online compilers seem to live in Linux ([checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)). I don't expect the online compiler to open a browser for me, but I did expect the code to run without an error. Ah, and forget [Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248000/why-can-i-not-use-xdg-open-and-gnome-open-in-mac) (personal laptop, limiting my machines).

Since I have no other Linux machine to check, my question is: Can I expect that this code will work in most of the major Linux distributions?

Maybe the fact that it failed on online compilers is misleading.

---

PS: This is for my post on [God of Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319020/275467), so no worries about security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Antti Haapala already completely [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537006/1475978) the question, I thought some comments about the approach, and an example function making safe use trivial, might be useful.

---

`xdg-open` is part of desktop integration utilities from freedesktop.org, as part of the [Portland project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland_Project). One can expect them to be available on any computer running a desktop environment [participating in freedesktop.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org). This includes GNOME, KDE, and Xfce.

Simply put, **this is the recommended way** of opening a resource (be it a file or URL) when a desktop environment is in use, in whatever application the user prefers.

If there is no desktop environment in use, then there is no reason to expect `xdg-open` to be available either.

---

For Linux, I would suggest using a dedicated function, perhaps along the following lines. First, a couple of internal helper functions:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
//
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
//
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Number of bits in an unsigned long. */
#define  ULONG_BITS  (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))

/* Helper function to open /dev/null to a specific descriptor.
*/
static inline int devnullfd(const int fd)
{
    int  tempfd;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    do {
        tempfd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    } while (tempfd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (tempfd == -1)
        return errno;

    if (tempfd != fd) {
        if (dup2(tempfd, fd) == -1) {
            const int  saved_errno = errno;
            close(tempfd);
            return errno = saved_errno;
        }
        if (close(tempfd) == -1)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Helper function to close all except small descriptors
   specified in the mask. For obvious reasons, this is not
   thread safe, and is only intended to be used in recently
   forked child processes. */
static void closeall(const unsigned long  mask)
{
    DIR           *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    int            dfd;

    dir = opendir("/proc/self/fd/");
    if (!dir) {
        /* Cannot list open descriptors.  Just try and close all. */
        const long  fd_max = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
        long        fd;

        for (fd = 0; fd < ULONG_BITS; fd++)
            if (!(mask & (1uL << fd)))
                close(fd);

        for (fd = ULONG_BITS; fd <= fd_max; fd++)
            close(fd);

        return;
    }

    dfd = dirfd(dir);

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)))
        if (ent->d_name[0] >= '0' && ent->d_name[0] <= '9') {
            const char *p = &ent->d_name[1];
            int         fd = ent->d_name[0] - '0';

            while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
                fd = (10 * fd) + *(p++) - '0';

            if (*p)
                continue;

            if (fd == dfd)
                continue;

            if (fd < ULONG_MAX && (mask & (1uL << fd)))
                continue;

            close(fd);
        }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

`closeall(0)` tries hard to close all open file descriptors, and `devnullfd(fd)` tries to open `fd` to `/dev/null`. These are used to make sure that even if the user spoofs `xdg-open`, no file descriptors are leaked; only the file name or URL is passed.

On non-Linux POSIXy systems, you can replace them with something more suitable. On BSDs, use `closefrom()`, and handle the first `ULONG_MAX` descriptors in a loop.

The `xdg_open(file-or-url)` function itself is something along the lines of

```
/* Launch the user-preferred application to open a file or URL.
   Returns 0 if success, an errno error code otherwise.
*/ 
int xdg_open(const char *file_or_url)
{
    pid_t  child, p;
    int    status;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (!file_or_url || !*file_or_url)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Fork the child process. */
    child = fork();
    if (child == -1)
        return errno;
    else
    if (!child) {
        /* Child process. */

        uid_t  uid = getuid();  /* Real, not effective, user. */
        gid_t  gid = getgid();  /* Real, not effective, group. */

        /* Close all open file descriptors. */
        closeall(0);

        /* Redirect standard streams, if possible. */
        devnullfd(STDIN_FILENO);
        devnullfd(STDOUT_FILENO);
        devnullfd(STDERR_FILENO);

        /* Drop elevated privileges, if any. */
        if (setresgid(gid, gid, gid) == -1 ||
            setresuid(uid, uid, uid) == -1)
            _Exit(98);

        /* Have the child process execute in a new process group. */
        setsid();

        /* Execute xdg-open. */
        execlp("xdg-open", "xdg-open", file_or_url, (char *)0);

        /* Failed. xdg-open uses 0-5, we return 99. */
        _Exit(99);
    }

    /* Reap the child. */
    do {
        status = 0;
        p = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    } while (p == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (p == -1)
        return errno;

    if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        /* Killed by a signal. Best we can do is I/O error, I think. */
        return errno = EIO;
    }

    switch (WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
    case 0: /* No error. */
        return errno = 0; /* It is unusual, but robust to explicitly clear errno. */
    case 1: /* Error in command line syntax. */
        return errno = EINVAL;      /* Invalid argument */
    case 2: /* File does not exist. */
        return errno = ENOENT;      /* No such file or directory */
    case 3: /* A required tool could not be found. */
        return errno = ENOSYS;      /* Not implemented */
    case 4: /* Action failed. */
        return errno = EPROTO;      /* Protocol error */
    case 98: /* Identity shenanigans. */
        return errno = EACCES;      /* Permission denied */
    case 99: /* xdg-open does not exist. */
        return errno = ENOPKG;      /* Package not installed */
    default:
        /* None of the other values should occur. */
        return errno = ENOSYS;      /* Not implemented */
    }
}
```

As already mentioned, it tries hard to close all open file descriptors, redirects the standard streams to `/dev/null`, ensures the effective and real identity matches (in case this is used in a setuid binary), and passes success/failure using the child process exit status.

The `setresuid()` and `setresgid()` calls are only available on OSes that have saved user and group ids.  On others, use `seteuid(uid)` and `setegid()` instead.

This implementation tries to balance user configurability with security. Users can set the `PATH` so that their favourite `xdg-open` gets executed, but the function tries to ensure that no sensitive information or privileges are leaked to that process.

(Environment variables could be filtered, but they should not contain sensitive information in the first place, and we don't really know which ones a desktop environment uses.  So better not mess with them, to keep user surprises to a minimum.)

As a minimal test `main()`, try the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  arg, status;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILE-OR-URL ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This example program opens each specified file or URL\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "xdg-open(1), and outputs success or failure for each.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++)
        if (xdg_open(argv[arg])) {
            printf("%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else
            printf("%s: Opened.\n", argv[arg]);

    return status;
}
```

As the SPDX license identifier states, this example code is licensed under [Creative Commons Zero 1.0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). Use it any way you wish, in any code you want.

Comment: Ah Nomimal, as always, you know so much when it comes to low level C! What is "POSIXy"? I searched online, and found several meanings..

Comment: @gsamaras: By "POSIXy", I mean those systems that implement most or all of IEEE Standard 1003.1™, also known as [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  Includes Linux and BSDs at least; I'm not sure about others, because I am not up to date.  Lots of Unixes are very POSIXy, although you might need to install additional libraries and utilities.

Comment: @gsamaras: I belatedly noticed I hadn't emphasized enough that it is definitely specific to desktop environments only, not available in non-DEs, and added a note about that in the second section. I hope I didn't mislead anyone...

Answer (score 1):

The `xdg-open` is part of the [`xdg-utils`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/). They're almost always installed with the GUI desktop of any Linux distribution.

A Linux distribution can be installed without any Graphical User Interface, on servers say, and most probably then they would lack `xdg-open`.

Instead of `system`, you could - and should - use `fork` + `exec` - if `exec` fails then `xdg-open` could not be executed.

The online compilers most probably don't have any Desktop GUI installed on them, thus the lack of that utility.

Comment: Any idea why the online compilers don't have it, despite the fact that their OS is Linux? Thanks for the answer and the tip, which is correct.

Comment: @gsamaras because they don't have any Desktop GUI installed on them :P why would they.

Comment: There are other programs that one could try to use in absense of `xdg-open`, but these are even less seldom installed by default.

Comment: I am not interested in that, since all I want is to have code in my Chronos Post that will be easily ready to be copy-pasted-compiled-executed! You can try it yourself too, if you like! In any case, good to know, because future readers might be interested!

Comment: @gsamaras What would you expect `xdg-open` to do on an online service? Open a window within your web browser?

Comment: No @IanAbbott, that's exactly what I am saying in my question!!! I don't expect to work in the sense that it will open a browser, but I would expect to not see an error. That's why I asked the question, and Antti answered. Do you think I should rephrase that part of my question: "I know that I wouldn't see the image in an online compiler."? It was unclear maybe?

Comment: @gsamaras I'm not sure what you'd expect it to do. Even if `xdg-open` is installed (which would be unusual for a GUI-less server box), it could still return a different error. Even if the URL is valid, `xdg-open` might return an error if it cannot find a suitable program to open it with. For example, a URL using the http or https scheme would normally require some sort of web-browser to be installed, which again would be unusual for a GUI-less server.

Comment: That would indicate that `xdg-open` is available. This is what the whole question was about @IanAbbott.